# Variable declaration / "option explicit" in R

Tags: r

R is fantastic: lean and flexible, but powerful and open. For small tasks it is convenient if one does not have to declare each variable before use. BUT: esp. in larger projects, small typos can mess up everything, possibly even without an eror message (see example)!

Is there a workaround? If not within plain R, possibly also by an editor that asks for a declaration block? Something like "option explicit" in VBA? I am aware of the very nice highlighting of same variables in the RStudio editor when marking it, but if variables in question are far apart this becomes less useful.

Just for clarity: I am not looking for a more elegant/less error-prone implementation of this function, which was created merely to provide a demo.

```
# without typo
fun <- function(x) {
  a <- x
  if (a<0) {
    if (a > -50) x <- -1 else x <- -2
  }
  return(x)
}

# even if masters will spot the typo on the first glance...
fun.typo <- function(x) {
  a <- x
  if (a<0) {
    if (a > -50) x <- -1 else X <- -2
  }
  return(x)
}

fun( 50) # 50
fun(-40) # -1
fun(-60) # -2

fun.typo( 50) #  50
fun.typo(-40) #  -1
fun.typo(-60) # -60 (*** unintended, should be -2 ***)
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `ifelse` instead: `x <- ifelse(a > -50, -1, -2)`

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks, but I am not looking for a more elegant way to write this particular function. In fact, I wrote this functions merely to demonstarte the problem - which usually occurs in huge scripts I wouldn't dare to bother anyone of you.

Comment: Not a matter of elegance, but more a matter of avoiding this kind of typo. Saying that, you are free to fight with this.

Comment: A very fishy solution would be to test whether the environment was correctly set at the beginning of the function. It works for this example...

Comment: @VincentGuillemot: Thanks, but I have to admit I don't really understand your suggestion. MayI ask you to further elaborate on it? Every advice is welcome!

Comment: I elaborated in an answer, I have to say that it would be nice to have a cleaner (than mine) answer to this question! Also, I am not very comfortable with changing an input variable, and return it as an output: this could lead to other mistakes... But even this "good practice rule" wouldn't prevent you from making the kind of mistake you would like to avoid.

Comment: From what I see, I would say that this kind of problem is probably hard to solve in a general case, so your best bet would probably be not to use dangerous constructs, that is, don't make a single function very long, split it into smaller chunks (own, separate functions); try to vectorise operations (for example using `ifelse` instead of `if`, if possible); try not to use `return` for simply returning the last object of the function call (that is, `ifelse` could be the last line in your function, without explicit `return`). I think simplicity will ensure bug-free code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very "dirty" solution would be to systematically check that the function's local environment is not changed after the "preamble".

```
fun <- function(x) {
  a <- x
  ls1 <- ls()
  if (a<0) {
    if (a > -50) x <- -1 else x <- -2
  }
  ls2 <- ls()
  print(list(c(ls1,"ls1"),ls2))
  if (!setequal(c(ls1,"ls1"), ls2)) stop("Something went terribly wrong!")
  return(x)
}

fun.typo <- function(x) {
  a <- x
  ls1 <- ls()
  if (a<0) {
    if (a > -50) x <- -1 else X <- -2
  }
  ls2 <- ls()
  print(list(c(ls1,"ls1"),ls2))
  if (!setequal(c(ls1,"ls1"), ls2)) stop("Something went terribly wrong!")
  return(x)
}
```

With this "solution", `fun.typo(-60)` no longer silently gives a wrong answer...

Comment: +1 for this creative answer! Could even think of sth. like setdiff to find out what went wrong. "Declaration" would then look like `VarXYZ <- numeric`. Small drawback (or bonus, as desired): `VarXYZ <- "Uhps"`would not give an error b/o type mismatch (numeric/char).